# Should I use `LockModeType.NONE` for an insert and read only table?

Tags: database, jpa

Say I have a table that I only perform `insert` and `select` e.g. `AuthenticationLog` and all the columns are marked as `updatable=false`.  Is it preferable to just use `LockModeType.NONE` in that situation or should I still use `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks OK. But actually it depends on your needs. NONE allows row to be deleted while other entityManager tries to read it.